# jQuery does not work for navbar in Materialize CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am trying to use the jQuery load () method to make a Master Page.
This is the main HTML and Jquery code block.

```js
$("#nav-wrapper").load("untitled2/navbar.html");
```

```html
<body>
  <nav id="nav-wrapper"></nav>
</body>
```

The code in the page where the navbar is locatedt

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
      <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
         <li><a href="#!"> <i class="small material-icons">add</i>K. Adi </a></li>
      </ul>
      <a class="btn dropdown-button" href="#!"
           data-activates="dropdown2">DROPDOWN<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

But this is the result.
Dropdown and logo do not appear.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRvoO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the address jQuery went to for the loading.

```js
$("#nav-wrapper").load("untitled2/navbar.html");
```

Change this code this way.

```js
$("#nav-wrapper").load("../untitled2/navbar.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

The JS file in MaterializeCSS depends on jQuery, so you have to first download and import jquery.js and after that materializecss.js
Useful links:

https://jquery.com/download/
http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Hope it helps solving your issue